# Need recommendations on hardware, IP-based time punch clocks

Tags: time

I hope this is the right place to ask this type of question. If not, please vote to move to a more appropriate place.

I have a homebrew, online time clock system we've built for our organization. It runs on Apache/PHP5 and a PostgreSQL database. Recently, there have been talks of added physical punch clock locations in remote areas. Based on initial scouring, we can only find punch clocks that come with their own specialized software. We're looking for something a little more open.

Basically, we're looking for hardware that would hopefully have some of these abilities:

- TCP/IP based, Power over Ethernet preferable but not required
- Ability to configure the clock to send information over SSL to a web application

Really, what we would like to do is send a POST request, XML, etc. from the hardware time clock to a script on our web server.

Does anyone have any recommendations on where I might find something that like? Has anyone had any experience working with systems like this and could offer advice?

I really appreciate any help you can provide!

Comment: I'm really itching to recommend you get a couple of those TouchPads that are going out and build a tablet interface for them and then use those instead.

Comment: A nice idea, but we need something we can physical mount and secure to a wall.

Comment: Well the thing has a humongous bezel, I'd imagine that anyone with a decent grade in woodshop would be able to construct a nice frame mount for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked with the [HandPunch 1000E](http://www.handpunch.com/) in the past.  It basically does RS-232 over ethernet, so I'm sure there would be an easy way to poll that information on a regular basis.  They appear to be highly customizable and fairly open.